# Problems with tables borders

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have wierd problem with my table,
As normal I want borders around my Table Heads and Table Cells,
But for some reason it only gives me a border around the whole table.
How can I fix this?

Images and code attached

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zamH.png)

HTML;

```
                    <table width='100%'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Maandag</th>
                        <th>Dinsdag</th>
                        <th>Woensdag</th>
                        <th>Donderdag</th>
                        <th>Vrijdag</th>
                        <th>Zaterdag</th>
                        <th>Zondag</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>#</td>
                        <td>#</td>
                        <td>#</td>
                        <td>#</td>
                        <td>#</td>
                        <td>#</td>
                        <td>#</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

CSS;

```
table, th, td {
background-color: white;
border: solid black 3px;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted in your your question *does*  put borders not only around the whole table, but also around every `td` and `th`.

I suppose you might not want the cells to have seperate borders. In this case you should apply the borders only to `td` and `th` (i.e. the cells) and in addition apply `border-collapse: collapse;` to the table itself:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid black 3px;
}
```

```html
<table width='100%'>
  <tr>
    <th>Maandag</th>
    <th>Dinsdag</th>
    <th>Woensdag</th>
    <th>Donderdag</th>
    <th>Vrijdag</th>
    <th>Zaterdag</th>
    <th>Zondag</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you but this does not work for me could it be that me using bootstrap makes these problems because even when i litteraly copy your code it still wont work

Comment: Well, you should have written in your question that you are using Bootstrap - we can't smell that ;-)

Comment: I know my fault i dont post things too often, but can that be the problem?

Comment: Of course: Bootstrap uses a lot of CSS styles that have to be considered when adding additional CSS

Comment: For every CSS rule you add, you have to make sure it overwrites any Bootstrap rules there might already be. For this purpose you need to use CSS selectors that are more **specific** than the Bootstrap rules, so it's a matter of *CSS specifity*

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this is to be careful with which CSS selectors you are using, and not use the table selector as a whole. For help with simple table values and alternatives, look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#table_content.

```
     thead { background-color: white; border: solid black 3px; }
     th{ background-color: white; border: solid black 3px; }
     td{ background-color: white; border: solid black 3px; }
```

Answer (score -1):

@remi03
can you try these codes
original:
bu kodları bir denermisiniz.

```
.baslik th{
  border: solid maroon 2px;
  padding: 0;
}
.icerik td{
  border: solid dodgerblue 2px;
  padding: 0;
}

<table width='100%'>
  <tr class="baslik">
    <th>Maandag</th>
    <th>Dinsdag</th>
    <th>Woensdag</th>
    <th>Donderdag</th>
    <th>Vrijdag</th>
    <th>Zaterdag</th>
    <th>Zondag</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="icerik">
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>#</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).